# Spring - ConfigurationProperties Usage

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Currently, I'm working on a project which uses Spring configuration and I've run into a design issue.

**I've posted a simplified code segments below.**

Let's say my application has 2 clients which are Spring `@Component`s and use `@Value` to inject configuration values.

```java
@Component
public class FirstClient implements Client {

    private String hello;
    public FirstClient(@Value("hello.first") String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
    // do some stuff with hello
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SecondClient implements Client {

    private String hello;
    public SecondClient(@Value("hello.second") String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
    // do some stuff with hello
}
```

By using this approach, I can easily `@Autowire` newly created Spring components. However, coming from "non-Spring background", I find it somewhat problematic to *magically* use before mentioned annotations for any code action.

My second approach would be an introduction of configuration class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hello")
public class DummyProperties {

    private String first;
    private String second;

    // get/set omitted
}
```

```java
public class FirstClient implements Client {

    private String hello;

    public FirstClient(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
    // do some stuff with hello
}
```

```java
public class SecondClient implements Client {

    private String hello;

    public SecondClient(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
    // do some stuff with hello
}
```

Joining logic would be:

```java
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DummyProperties.class)
public class ClientCreator {

    private DummyProperties props;
    public ClientCreator(DummyProperties props) {
        this.props = props;
    }

    public Client create(boolean isSatisfied) {
        // some custom check logic
        if (isSatisfied) {
            return new FirstClient(props.getFirst());
        } else {
            return new SecondClient(props.getSecond());
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't necessarily need to be a good flow.

Any recommendations or additional ideas?

Comment: Both approaches are equally valid. I tend to lean towards `@ConfigurationProperties` when I have a lot of properties or the properties structurally benefit from encapsulation, and `@Value` when there's just a small number to inject.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify he location of your configuration properties' file location at the beginning of your config class or main application class using above annotations or @PropertySource etc.,